# How to make app start at login or add to login items after install like dropbox? Xcode 11, Swift 5, MacOS 10.13+

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, xcode11, launching-application

I am trying to have my app start automatically when a user logs out and back in or after a reboot. The objective is to have the app there indefinitely unless a user closes out, but, to have it start back up when they reboot.

There are several tutorials I have followed and threads I have read but they all seem outdated. I am using this app on 3 different OS' including 10.13, 10.14 and 10.15. I seem to have most of the issues on 10.15 machines. I can't figure out why it is hit or miss whether the app starts on login and why sometimes it does not.

https://martiancraft.com/blog/2015/01/login-items/

https://theswiftdev.com/how-to-launch-a-macos-app-at-login/

I have code signed the application, sandbox is enabled, but maybe since the tutorials and information I have found is outdated I am missing something outside the code. This app is for internal company use only, and thus, I will not be submitting to the Apple. I intend to deploy to machines using our management software, and have built a .pkg to deploy the application + launcher into the applications folder and to run automatically after install.

Any help, cleanup, explanations or suggestions are welcome and appreciated.

Main App:

```
extension Notification.Name{
static let killLauncher = Notification.Name("killLauncher")
}

extension AppDelegate: NSApplicationDelegate{
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
      // Insert code here to initialize your application

          //assign variables for launcherhelper
          let launcherAppId = "Kinetic.KTGHelperLauncher"
          let runningApps = NSWorkspace.shared.runningApplications
          let isRunning = !runningApps.filter {$0.bundleIdentifier == launcherAppId }.isEmpty
          //set launcher to login item
          SMLoginItemSetEnabled(launcherAppId as CFString, true)
          //status check if running or not running
          if isRunning {
              DistributedNotificationCenter.default().post(name: .killLauncher, object: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!)
          }
      
      
      
      //configure button to display button in assets
      if let button = statusItem.button {
          button.image = NSImage(named:NSImage.Name("kinetic_websitemain_red"))
          
      }
      //builds menu on start
      constructMenu()
  }
}

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject {


let statusItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength:NSStatusItem.squareLength)



func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
}


@objc func TakeScreenshot(_ sender: Any){
    
    //get path to user download folder
    let dirPath = FileManager().urls(for:.downloadsDirectory, in:.userDomainMask)[0]
     
    //create time stamp of when picture is taken
    func CreateTimeStamp() -> Int32
    {
        return Int32(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)
    }
    
    
    var displayCount: UInt32 = 0;
    var result = CGGetActiveDisplayList(0, nil, &displayCount)
        if (result != CGError.success) {
            print("error: \(result)")
            return
        }
        let allocated = Int(displayCount)
        let activeDisplays = UnsafeMutablePointer<CGDirectDisplayID>.allocate(capacity: allocated)
        result = CGGetActiveDisplayList(displayCount, activeDisplays, &displayCount)

        if (result != CGError.success) {
            print("error: \(result)")
            return
        }

        for i in 1...displayCount {
            let unixTimestamp = CreateTimeStamp()
            let fileUrl = dirPath.appendingPathComponent("\(unixTimestamp)" + "_" + "\(i)" + ".jpg", isDirectory:false)
            let screenShot:CGImage = CGDisplayCreateImage(activeDisplays[Int(i-1)])!
            let bitmapRep = NSBitmapImageRep(cgImage: screenShot)
            let jpegData = bitmapRep.representation(using: NSBitmapImageRep.FileType.jpeg, properties: [:])!


            do {
                try jpegData.write(to: fileUrl, options: .atomic)
            }
            catch {print("error: \(error)")}
        }
    
}

@objc func kineticSelf(_ sender: Any){
    let kineticSelfUrl = URL(string: "/Library/Addigy/macmanage/MacManage.app")
    NSWorkspace.shared.openFile(kineticSelfUrl!.path)
    // NSWorkspace.shared.open(URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Library/Addigy/macmanage/MacManage.app"))
    
}


//function that opens kinetic helpdesk website
@objc func kineticHelpdesk(_ sender: Any){
    let kineticHelpdeskUrl = URL(string: "http://helpdesk.kinetictg.com")!
    NSWorkspace.shared.open(kineticHelpdeskUrl)
    
}
//function that takes user to teamviewer ktg site
@objc func kineticRemote(_ sender: Any){
    let kineticRemoteUrl = URL(string: "https://get.teamviewer.com/ktgsupport")!
    NSWorkspace.shared.open(kineticRemoteUrl)
    
}
//call kinetic
@objc func kineticHomepage(_ sender: Any){
    let url = URL(string: "https://kinetictg.com")!
    NSWorkspace.shared.open(url)
}


//function to build menu
func constructMenu(){
    let menu = NSMenu()
    
    
    
    //section for "Request Support"
    menu.addItem(NSMenuItem.separator())
    menu.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: "Request Support", action: nil, keyEquivalent:""))
        //support ticket
    menu.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: "Support Ticket", action:
        #selector(AppDelegate.kineticHelpdesk(_:)), keyEquivalent: ""))
        //remote support
    menu.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: "Remote Support", action:
         #selector(AppDelegate.kineticRemote(_:)), keyEquivalent: ""))
    
    //section for "Tools"
    menu.addItem(NSMenuItem.separator( ))
    menu.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: "Tools", action: nil, keyEquivalent:""))
        //start agent installation audit
    menu.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: "Take Screenshot", action:
        #selector(AppDelegate.TakeScreenshot(_:)), keyEquivalent: ""))
        //open self service
    menu.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: "Open Self Service", action:
        #selector(AppDelegate.kineticSelf(_:)), keyEquivalent: ""))
    
    //Section for "Info"
    menu.addItem(NSMenuItem.separator( ))
    menu.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: "Info", action: nil, keyEquivalent:""))
        //contact info
    menu.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: "Kinetic Homepage", action:
        #selector(AppDelegate.kineticHomepage(_:)), keyEquivalent: ""))
        //quit app
    menu.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: "Quit", action:
        #selector(NSApplication.terminate(_:)), keyEquivalent: "q"))
    
    statusItem.menu = menu
    
    
}
}
```

Launcher Application:

```
import Cocoa
//extension variable for launcher to kill launcher

extension Notification.Name {
static let killLauncher = Notification.Name("killLauncher")
}

@NSApplicationMain
class HelperAppDelegate: NSObject {

//terminate object
@objc func terminate(){
    NSApp.terminate(nil)
}

}

extension HelperAppDelegate: NSApplicationDelegate{

func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
 //main app identifier
    let mainAppIdentifier = "Kinetic.KTG-Helper"
    let runningApps = NSWorkspace.shared.runningApplications
    let isRunning = !runningApps.filter { $0.bundleIdentifier == mainAppIdentifier }.isEmpty
    //if app is running kill launcher entity and reset status of killlauncher
    if !isRunning {
        DistributedNotificationCenter.default().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.terminate), name: .killLauncher, object: mainAppIdentifier)
        
        let path = Bundle.main.bundlePath as NSString
        var components = path.pathComponents
        components.removeLast(3)
        components.append("MacOS")
        components.append("KTG Helper")
        
        let newPath = NSString.path(withComponents: components)
        
        NSWorkspace.shared.launchApplication(newPath)
    }
    else{
        self.terminate()
    }
}

//func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
//}
}
```

Comment: Instead of trying to manage this from the application itself, why not ask your users to add the application to their user Login Items? (You can, yourself, in your application, install a Login Item, but even then the user has the power to remove it.)

Comment: I can recommend that you have a look at https://github.com/sindresorhus/LaunchAtLogin. That's a Swift Package of which the author promises that it makes adding "Launch-at-login" functionality the work of seconds -- and that appears to be true: I use it successfully in one of my apps on macOS 10.15.7.

Comment: @matt The point is to make it seamless for the end user. They can very well remove it, however, it will be reinstalled after it detects it not running/uninstalled through our management platform. We do not want to rely on them adding it to their login items. I have about 600+ computers to deploy this on.

Comment: @cbjeukendrup i'll give this a look as a last result, however, I'd like to reliable implement it into the application itself if possible. Thanks for the resource!

Comment: I have rebuilt the application step by step following tutorials and to no success. Does it need to have a toggle that allows it to become a login item?